# Selecting rows that don't exist when joining two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

I have two tables that can be joined using one field:

```
Table_1: 

    emp_id  emp_name  department
    ------  --------  ----------
    1       Adam      Accounting
    2       Peter     Engineering
    3       Bruce     Engineering


Table_2: 

    emp_id  emp_salary
    ------  ----------
    1       1000 
    3       3500
    5       2000
```

I want to select the rows in table 2 that don't appear when joining the two tables (in this example emp_id=5). I have been trying the following statement but I am getting 0 rows:

```
select * from table_2 
where not exists
(
select * from table_1, table_2
where table_1.emp_id = table_2.emp_id);
```

Comment: There's no association between the two statements; your EXISTS clause will always return something as long as there's one ID that's in both tables... in other words it's always true and you need to link `table_2` to your EXISTS clause. This should help you to see that you only want a list of IDs in `table_2` that don't exist in `table_1`, which is a simpler proposition.

Comment: You should have use inner join instead

Comment: That is an inner join @sra1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So easy, just remove table_2 from sub-query:

```
select *
from table_2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table_1
                  where table_1.emp_id = table_2.emp_id);
```

Comment: Awesome and easy solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select * from table_2 
where
emp_id not in (select emp_id from table_1)
```

Comment: NOT IN is a bit dangerous if emp_id is nullable. If that's the case add where emp_id is not null to sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

select * from table_2 
where
emp_id not in (select emp_id from table_1)

You can use this query if emp_id is primary in both the table.